# Linux modules take a lot of space

Tags: kernel

I'm using the 4.1.2 mainline kernel. The package with image and all modules has 207 MB of installed size.

I built a patched 4.1.6 kernel, taking the config from the current kernel and now the drivers themselves take 2G!

```
marcin@asus ~/4.1.6/lib/modules/4.1.6/kernel $ du -sh *
19M arch
16M crypto
2,0G    drivers
213M    fs
636K    kernel
7,0M    lib
240K    mm
349M    net
132M    sound
marcin@asus ~/4.1.6/lib/modules/4.1.6/kernel $ du -sh /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/*
2,5M    /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/arch
1,2M    /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/crypto
155M    /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/drivers
16M /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/fs
100K    /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/kernel
700K    /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/lib
668K    /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/misc
16K /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/mm
17M /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/net
13M /lib/modules/4.1.2-040102-generic/kernel/sound
```

Why does the new build take so much more space in comparison with the old one? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Could you furnish your posting with a question ?  It's merely a statement right now.

Comment: Nobody but you can tell. You've started the right way: `du -hsx ~/4.1.6/lib/modules/4.1.6/kernel/divers/*`. Just recurse through the tree to find which directory consumes that much. A possible cause is that you've (inadvertently at least) mixed your kernel sources with the compiled results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel I used was stripped afterwards. My modules were not stripped. Hence they were so big.